# If we randomly pick 7 balls from 49 balls numbered from 1 to 49, what is the probability that we get 5 or more balls with number less than 10?

Tags: probability

> If we randomly pick 7 balls from 49 balls numbered from 1 to 49, what is the probability that we get 5 or more balls with number less than 10?

I know that there are totally 49*48*47*46*45*44*43 cases of drawing 7 balls.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need the hypergeometric distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 9 balls less than 10, and only 5 of the picked balls have to be less than 10. That means that there are ${9 \choose 5}=126$ combinations of balls that can be picked among the 5 restricted balls. After those 5 balls are picked, only 44 balls are left. We have two balls left to pick, and the other two balls can be any of the other 44 balls, which is $44 \choose 2$. The total combinations are $49 \choose 5 $We end up with $$\frac{{9 \choose 7}{44 \choose2}}{49 \choose 7}$$

Comment: -1 Does order matter? It seems to do so in your denominator and $44 \times 43$, but not in your numerator of ${9 \choose 5}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yikes, thank you. Will fix that.

Comment: The total combinations are $49 \choose 7$ not $49 \choose 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Picking $5$ balls numbered less than $10$: $\binom{9}{5}\cdot\binom{40}{2}$ (choose $5$ and another $2$ with higher numbers)
Picking $6$ balls numbered less than $10$: $\binom{9}{6}\cdot\binom{40}{1}$
Picking $7$ balls numbered less than $10$: $\binom{9}{7}$
So the number of ways to choose *at least* $5$ balls numbered less than $10$ is $$\binom{9}{5}\cdot\binom{40}{2}+\binom{9}{6}\cdot\binom{40}{1}+\binom{9}{7}$$
and the number of ways to draw $7$  balls is $\binom{49}{7}$
(I assumed the order of the drawing is not important). So, the required probability will be:...

Comment: @mathguy: No, it does not: I did not count $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ since I chose the $5$ balls from $1,...,9$ and the remaining $2$ from $10,11,...,49$

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** How many ways are there to pick 7 balls? Does order matter to you?

**Hint:** How many ways are there to pick 5 balls with number less than 10 (and 2 balls with number greater than 10)?

**Hint:** How many ways are there to pick 6 balls with number less than 10 (and 1 balls with number greater than 10)?

**Hint:** How many ways are there to pick 7 balls with number less than 10 (and 0 balls with number greater than 10)?